# Fabric.js canvas loadFromDatalessJSON

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net, fabricjs

Привет, я пытаюсь загрузить объекты на canvas из другого canvas'а предварительно сериализованного и отправленного в контроллер.

```
function canvasToImage() {
    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
    var image = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());    


    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../Home/UploadImage/",
        data: { imageData: image },
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert('success')
        }
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Принимающий метод

```
   public ActionResult UploadImage(string imageData)
    {              

            Session["imageSession"] = imageData;
            return RedirectToAction("Apply");
    }
```

Отправляю дальше в на другое представление

```
 public ActionResult SendImage()
    {
        string image = (string)Session["imageSession"];
        return Json(image, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Здесь пытаюсь загрузить в новый canvas

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "../../Home/SendImage",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // process the data coming back
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(JSON.parse(item));
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
})
```

При попытке загрузки в новый canvas консоль в браузере возвращает ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1678' in {"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":100,"top":100,"width":20,...
```

Comment: МММ может я чегото не понимаю, но накой???? вы картинку через JSON передаёте? И как понять загрузить объекты из другого канваса?

Comment: Это не картинка, это макет визитки мне нужно его сохранить в виде обьекта, чтобы была возможность редактирования потом.

Comment: Canvas это именно картинка, нарисованая Fabric, передавайте объекты которые отображаются а не картинку)))

Comment: Для интереса попробуйте создать Canvas и кликните на нём правой кнопкой...

Comment: Десериализация, SVG парсер

Как и в сериализации, есть 2 способа загрузить canvas из строки: из представления JSON и SVG. Для JSON существуют методы fabric.Canvas#loadFromJSON и fabric.Canvas#loadFromDatalessJSON. Для SVG — методы fabric.loadSVGFromURL и fabric.loadSVGFromString.
Вот что я хочу сделать

Comment: loadFromDatalessJSON возвращает данные в таком виде и как я понял на основе этих данных можно отрисовать объекты


`{"objects":[{"type":"path","left":143,"top":143,"width":175,"height":151,"fill":"#231F20","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":-19,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":false,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"path":"/assets/dragon.svg"}],"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}`

Comment: Обьект в виде строки возвращается, а разве JSON.parse не должен его в JSON преобразовывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась заменой вот этого

```
success: function (data) {
        // process the data coming back
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(JSON.parse(item));
        });
    }
```

На это

```
success: function (data) {
            // process the data coming back
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, item) {

                canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(item);
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
        },
```